# Can I put non-editable text into a form field with pure CSS?

Tags: css, forms, user-input

I'm trying to make a form input field that looks like

[image: Form field]

where domain.com/username/ is non-editable text (that doesn't get submitted as form data), but the user can type what they want at the end of it. I know I can use Javascript for this, but is there a clean, non-hacky way to do it with CSS alone? Of course the username will vary in size, so the editable text needs to start in the right place.

Comment: I am going to say no.  CSS doesn't really have all that much to do with an input's value.  CSS is for styling.  So even if you use something like `:before` or `:after` to make `domain.com/username/` appear there it still won't be setting the value attribute.  You are better off populating this data via a server side language or using two inputs.  One input that is read only for your `domain.com/username/` and another for the user to enter the slug.  With two inputs side by side you could try to style it to look like a single input.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need the default browser-style inputs and can edit the HTML, you can create your custom fields like this - http://jsfiddle.net/Aprillion/aJQ6M/:

HTML:

```
<label class="looks_like_input">
  domain.com/username/
  <input type="text" value="all-about-kitties">
</label>
```

CSS:

```
.looks_like_input {
    border: 1px inset;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.looks_like_input input {
    border: 0;
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

Comment: The label tag isn't a great choice here since the url itself doesn't really describe the input field.  Otherwise, it looks close enough to fool the user.

Comment: @cimmanon good point, but well,, if you don't want to handle the click-on-fixed-text event yourself in javascript, this is the best i know of

Answer (score 0):

why not just label the domain.com/username/ and then put the input?

put this in your CSS

```
#page{float:left;}
#box{border:1px inset; height:30px;}
.text_field{border:none;}
```

and this goes in HTML

```
<div id="page">
<div id="box">
<input class="text_field" style="float:right; min-width:50px;width:50px;max-width:130px;text-align:left;" size="5" onkeyup="this.size=this.value.length+1;this.style.width='auto'" type="text">
<label class="prefix_for_input" style="float:right;">http://millerpath.tumblr.com/</label>
</div>
</div>
```

you might wanna fix some things around here.